# How to setup the autosave PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Colleagues, could you share your thoughts or advice?

When with PhpStorm I have constantly (and I think like everyone else) many tabs are open. I write code in one, then move to another, and so on.

I have a question, does PhpStorm auto-save the result when I switch from the current tab to another one? That is, is the current code in the current folder saved when I go to another file of another tab?

Usually, if I don't remember whether I saved a tab or not, I just run through all the tabs and press <kbd>CTRL+S</kbd>, which is not very convenient.

Now, if there was an autosave function when switching to another tab (or does it already exist)?

I heard that PhpStorm already has a built-in autosave feature. How it works, can you explain, if I'm on a different tab, does it keep the old one? Or does it save all open tabs? or does it save everything I've edited, even when the tab is closed?

Comment: See the answer + can be when switching to another app; executing command in built-in Terminal, Deployment etc. It does not auto-save on file close (bit it remembers the changes). The actual save for already closed file will be performed when `Ctrl+S` is pressed or global autosave is triggered (like running etc)

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/working-with-source-code.html#auto_save

Comment: *"Usually, if I don't remember whether I saved a tab or not, I just run through all the tabs and press CTRL+S, which is not very convenient."* This is unnecessary (for all tabs). `Ctrl+S` is assigned to "Save ALL" by default so you just press it once and it will save even closed tabs with pending modifications. The "Save Current document" has no shortcut and you need to do that manually.

Comment: If you want to see if there are still unsaved pending changes in some currently opened Editor tab, then enable `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Editor Tabs | Mark modified (*)` option and you will have an asterisk next to the file icon in the Editor Tab (may not be shown if you decide to not to show file type icons there).

Answer (score 0):

PhPStorm has a built-in autosave which, by default, saves your files when compiling, running, debugging, performing version control operations, closing a file or a project, or quitting the IDE.

Comment: How does it know what action you're performing (other than closing the file or project)?  If I type a character into a document I have open in PHPStorm and then go to my terminal and ls -l in that folder, I can see it was updated.  It seems to save it every time I hit a key, unless it's doing it when I update the document AND THEN PHPStorm loses focus?